# iOS Facebook SDK 3.2.1 Feed post error

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I am working on iOS App and it has a simple facebook sharing functionality, basically it allows you to share a link to this app by posting in feed.

I am using facebook SDK 3.2.1 this way:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = 
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
        @"Test tweet", @"name",
        @"Test", @"description",
        @"http://myapplink.com", 
        @"link",
        @"http://myapppicture.com/picture.jpg", 
        @"picture",
        nil];

[FBWebDialogs presentFeedDialogModallyWithSession:nil
    parameters:params
    handler:^(FBWebDialogResult result, NSURL *resultURL, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error publishing story.");
        } else {
            if (result == FBWebDialogResultDialogNotCompleted) {
                NSLog(@"User canceled story publishing.");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"No error!");
            }
         }
     }];
```

The problem is: when this code runs, it brings up facebook login dialog and after I log in, I see this error on screen: "An error occured. Please try again later".
There's nothing logged in console, but if i close this dialogs, it only logs "User canceled story publishing."

Application settings are very basic - I've setup everything just like facebook asked to do:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/

My question is: has anybody came across the same problem? what can be possible solution?
Thanks!

Comment: I managed to find answer by myself, but I am not allowed to post it for a while because of my low reputation - I'll post the answer in 8 hours. Generally, the solution is to add @"app_id" key with your app id to params dictionary

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Now this was fairly simple and I feel kinda stupid :)
But anyway, I hope this will help anybody who will be in the same problem.

Generally, I solved the problem by adding one more key-value pair to my "params" dictionary - value @"my_facebook_app_id" for key @"app_id".
So the correct dictionary looks like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"11111111", @"app_id",
                               @"Test tweet", @"name",
                               @"Test", @"description",
                               @"http://sometestsite", @"link",
                             @"http://site.com/testimage.jpg", @"picture",
                               nil];
```

Facebook SDK says that app_id key is "Required, but automatically specified by most SDKs" - and even though I provided my app_id via MyApp-Info.plist file, it seems like it was not automatically specified (or I did something wrong).

So if you have the same problem, try adding this @"app_id" key - this should help.